# How to display USD and Bitcoin price on Classified ads?

Tags: api

Hello i'm developing this website https://buysellcarwithbitcoin.com/ how can i display the USD price of classified ads also converted in Bitcoin ? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want that cars could be paid by Bitcoin you need some payment gateway.

Otherwise, if you want just to display prices in Bitcoin you can use some blockchain.info API to get the price for it. 
For example, this URL will return you how much is 5000 BTC:  https://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=USD&value=5000

Comment: yes i want only to display it, so how can do it? thanks so much

Comment: Use some api 
for example, this is how much btc is $5000 https://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=USD&value=5000

Comment: i not understand :-( i'm using Wordpress, but not know what i need to add and where

Comment: for example this is API from Coindesk, but where i need to paste it? https://www.coindesk.com/api/

Comment: That is more PHP code / Wordpress code related question. You need to put a code snippet that will make an api call with the appropriate price.

Answer (score 0):

Some bitcoin exchanges will offer an API to return the current BTC price, so you can pull data from them, divide the item price into btc price, and display the resulting btc price to your customers.

A quick search brings up a [Coinbase API for btc price](https://www.coindesk.com/api/) that would probably work for you.

Comment: i know i must use API but not know what and where paste codes

Comment: Your question relates more to 'how to work with an API call' than it does 'how the bitcoin network works'. You may find better answers in another forum.